# Unable to send emails to other domain using amazon ses

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

How to send mails through amazon simple email services.

I have set up my **amazon simple email services** account for my domain and verified it, but I can only send emails to email ids related to my domain like **username@mydomain.com**. I am unable to send emails to other domains like **username@gmail.com**, **username@yahoo.com**, etc. Please Tell me if I have to do something related to my amazon web services account.

```
$config = Array(
      'protocol' => 'mail',
      'protocol' => 'smtp',
      'smtp_host' => email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com,
      'smtp_port' => 465,
      'smtp_user' => ##############,
      'smtp_pass' => ###########################,
      'mailtype'  => 'html', 
      'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
);

$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");    
$this->email->from(user@mydomain.com, 'User');
$this->email->to($to);  
$this->email->subject($subject);
$this->email->message($message);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you have completed your setup and testing, you need to [request to be removed from Sandbox Mode and be granted production access](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html).

> To help protect our customers from fraud and abuse and to help you establish your trustworthiness to ISPs and email recipients, we do not immediately grant unlimited Amazon SES usage to new users. New users are initially placed in the Amazon SES sandbox.

Among the the restrictions in sandbox mode:

> You can only send mail to the Amazon SES mailbox simulator and to verified email addresses and domains.

There are two ways to request production access, either by opening a support case, or submitting a request form, both of which are discussed at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html.